# How to parse Json Array and Json Object having two keys and values in android?

Tags: android, json

I want to populate my spinner from wallet array from SQL database and then store the wallet id which is being selected by the user in the particular user details, not the wallet name. I have written this particular code and o have added the screenshot as well for the error.

**Android Part**

```
public class User extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ArrayList<Populate> listItems;
LinkedHashMap<String,String> walletId;
Button logout,editdetails;
SharedPreferences sp;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
public static final String DEFAULT = "N/A";
TextView usermail;
String email;
int id;
public static final int DEFAULTI = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);



    listItems = new ArrayList<>();

    usermail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usermail);
    editdetails = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editdetails);
    logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);

    sp = getSharedPreferences("Login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    email = sp.getString("email", DEFAULT);
    usermail.setText("Welcome " + email);
    id = sp.getInt("id",DEFAULTI);

    logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /** pref = getSharedPreferences("Login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
             editor = pref.edit();
             editor.putBoolean("loginfirst",false);
             editor.commit();**/
            Intent i = new Intent(User.this, Login.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
public void onEdit(View v){
    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask();
    backgroundTask.execute(String.valueOf(id));

}

class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    ArrayList<Populate> list;
    String add_info_url;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        list=new ArrayList<>();
        add_info_url = "http://192.168.2.6/Deal%20Engine/editdetails.php";

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        listItems.addAll(list);


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("Login",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


        Intent i = new Intent(User.this, EditDetails.class);
        startActivity(i);


    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(add_info_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String dataString = URLEncoder.encode("id", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(id), "UTF-8");

            Log.d("id", String.valueOf(id));
            bufferedWriter.write(dataString);
            Log.d("Result", dataString);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            String finalJson = buffer.toString();
            Log.d("String", finalJson);

            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
            JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("user");
            StringBuffer finalBufferedData = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
                int status_code = finalObject.getInt("status_code");
                String status_desc = finalObject.getString("status_desc");
                String user_id = finalObject.getString("user_id");
                int id = finalObject.getInt("id");
                String name=finalObject.getString("name");
                String pass= finalObject.getString("pass");
                String location = finalObject.getString("location");
                String cards=finalObject.getString("cards");
                String category= finalObject.getString("category");
                String wallet = finalObject.getString("wallet");
                String operator=finalObject.getString("operator");
                String loyaltyProgram= finalObject.getString("loyaltyProgram");
                String membership= finalObject.getString("membership");
                JSONObject walletArrayObject = new JSONObject(finalObject.getString("wallet_array"));
                JSONArray walletArray = walletArrayObject.getJSONArray("wallets");
                Log.d("Arraysize",String.valueOf(walletArray));
                for(int j =0;j<walletArray.length();j++)
                {
                    JSONObject walletObject = walletArray.getJSONObject(j);
                    list.add(new Populate(String.valueOf(walletObject.getInt("id")),walletObject.getString("wallet_name")));
                }
                sp = getSharedPreferences("Login",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                editor=sp.edit();
                editor.putString("name",name);
                editor.putString("pass",pass);
                editor.putInt("id",id);
                editor.putString("location",location);
                editor.putString("cards",cards);
                editor.putString("category",category);
                editor.putString("wallet",wallet);
                editor.putString("operator",operator);
                editor.putString("wallets",String.valueOf(list));
                editor.putString("loyaltyProgram",loyaltyProgram);
                editor.putString("membership",membership);
                editor.commit();
                finalBufferedData.append(status_code + " - " + status_desc + " -" + user_id + " -"+id +  " -"+name+ " -"+list +"\n");
            }


            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            Log.d("Result", dataString);
            return finalBufferedData.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }


 }


}
```

**error I am getting**

```
06-29 12:53:08.015 28974-28988/com.example.tanmayjain.twowaycommunication D/String: {"user":[{"status_code":"1","status_desc":"Success","user_id":"482","id":"26","name":"tanmay ","pass":"a006b22f887f7d922bafa4c8186ccafd","location":"Ahmedabad","cards":"ICICI Bank","category":"Platinum","wallet":"","operator":"Vodafone","loyaltyProgram":"Any","membership":"All Time","wallet_array":"{\"wallets\":[{\"1\":[\"Paytm\"],\"2\":[\"Freecharge\"],\"3\":[\"Mobikwik\"],\"4\":[\"PayUmoney\"],\"5\":[\"CitrusCash\"],\"6\":[\"Airtel Money\"],\"7\":[\"Oxigen Wallet\"],\"8\":[\"OLAMoney\"],\"9\":[\"HDFC PayZapp\"],\"10\":[\"Chillr by HDFC\"],\"11\":[\"Pockets by ICICI bank\"],\"12\":[\"JioMoney\"],\"13\":[\"SBI Buddy\"],\"14\":[\"mRupee\"],\"15\":[\"Itzcash\"]}]}"}]}
06-29 12:53:08.015 28974-28988/com.example.tanmayjain.twowaycommunication D/Arraysize: [{"1":["Paytm"],"2":["Freecharge"],"3":["Mobikwik"],"4":["PayUmoney"],"5":["CitrusCash"],"6":["Airtel Money"],"7":["Oxigen Wallet"],"8":["OLAMoney"],"9":["HDFC PayZapp"],"10":["Chillr by HDFC"],"11":["Pockets by ICICI bank"],"12":["JioMoney"],"13":["SBI Buddy"],"14":["mRupee"],"15":["Itzcash"]}]
06-29 12:53:08.016 28974-28988/com.example.tanmayjain.twowaycommunication W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for id
06-29 12:53:08.016 28974-28988/com.example.tanmayjain.twowaycommunication W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
06-29 12:53:08.016 28974-28988/com.example.tanmayjain.twowaycommunication W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getInt(JSONObject.java:478)
06-29 12:53:08.016 28974-28988/com.example.tanmayjain.twowaycommunication W/System.err:     at com.example.tanmayjain.twowaycommunication.User$BackgroundTask.doInBackground(User.java:167)
06-29 12:53:08.017 28974-28988/com.example.tanmayjain.twowaycommunication W/System.err:     at com.example.tanmayjain.twowaycommunication.User$BackgroundTask.doInBackground(User.java:85)
06-29 12:53:08.017 28974-28988/com.example.tanmayjain.twowaycommunication W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
```

[I want to fetch id and wallet name from the array displayed in array size but i am getting this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi5f3.jpg)

Comment: php is not related

Comment: if($result){
   $output = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $output [$row["id"]][0]= $row["wallet_name"];
  }
  }
  $tempArray["wallets"][0] = $output;
 $usrArray["user"][0] = array( "status_code" => '1', "status_desc" => 'Success', "user_id"=>'482',"id"=>$id,"name"=>$name,"pass"=>$pass, "location" => $location, "cards" =>$cards, "category"=>$category,"wallet"=>$wallet,"operator"=>$operator,"loyaltyProgram"=>$loyaltyProgram,"membership"=>$membership,"wallet_array" =>json_encode($tempArray));
echo json_encode($usrArray);
}

Answer (score 0):

Your json is wrong, because your walletObject contains this:

```
{
"wallets": [{
    "1": ["Paytm"],
    "2": ["Freecharge"],
    "3": ["Mobikwik"],
    "4": ["PayUmoney"],
    "5": ["CitrusCash"],
    "6": ["Airtel Money"],
    "7": ["Oxigen Wallet"],
    "8": ["OLAMoney"],
    "9": ["HDFC PayZapp"],
    "10": ["Chillr by HDFC"],
    "11": ["Pockets by ICICI bank"],
    "12": ["JioMoney"],
    "13": ["SBI Buddy"],
    "14": ["mRupee"],
    "15": ["Itzcash"]
}]
}
```

You got the error because you would like to get the value of *id* property, but your json doesn't contains id field.

Your json has more problems:
 1. send an object instead of array (wallet_array)
 2. change your wallet object structure

I think you should use this json structure:

`{
    "user": [{
        "status_code": "1",
        "status_desc": "Success",
        "user_id": "482",
        "id": "26",
        "name": "tanmay ",
        "pass": "a006b22f887f7d922bafa4c8186ccafd",
        "location": "Ahmedabad",
        "cards": "ICICI Bank",
        "category": "Platinum",
        "wallet": "",
        "operator": "Vodafone",
        "loyaltyProgram": "Any",
        "membership": "All Time",
        "wallet_array": [{
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Paytm"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Freecharge"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Mobikwik"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "PayUmoney"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "CitrusCash"
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "Airtel Money"
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "name": "Oxigen Wallet"
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "name": "OLAMoney"
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "HDFC PayZapp"
            }
        ]
    }]
}`

Comment: I have done it in the above format but still  i am having problem in json object of wallet array. It's showing mismatch of values